# Regex expression and next symbol is not '('

Tags: regex

I want to have an expression, where the next symbol after found value is not "(".

I have the following base regex:

```
(([_A-Za-z]([_\w])+)|([A-Za-z]))
```

and text for example:

```
a3+red+42+_dv+Sy(w12+44)
```

Wished regex should return:

```
a3, red, _dv, w12
```

this base regex returns

```
a3, red, _dv, Sy, w12
```

but I need exclude 'Sy', because next symbol is "(".

I try the following:

```
(([_A-Za-z]([_\w])+)|([A-Za-z]))(\b)
```

but it returns

```
a3+, red+, _dv+, w12)
```

I not need to have next symbol, I need include only if the next symbol is not "(".

Comment: negative lookahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do three things:

- enclose the pattern in an atomic group (or at least the first part of your alternation that contains a quantifier)
- start your pattern with a word boundary (to quickly avoid useless positions)
- use a lookahead assertion to test the next character if any

result:

```
\b((?>[_A-Za-z]\w+)|[A-Za-z]\b)(?!\()
```

the point 1 is important to block the backtracking mechanism in this kind of situation: `Abcd(` Without it the pattern will succeed and return `Abc`. Using an atomic group, the pattern will match `Abcd` and since it can't to go back, it will fail with the next character.

Other way to write the pattern:

```
\b(?>[A-Za-z]\w*|_\w+)(?!\()
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gets one symbol from 'Sy' (matches S). How to exclude it at all?

Comment: @casimir Small grammatical gripe: "first part of you alternation" which I would happily edit out but it's below the requisite minimum characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect a single `_` in your input how about this regex:

```
\b[^\W\d]\w*+(?!\()
```

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\w` matches a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- [`[^\W\d]`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious) matches `[_a-zA-Z]`
- `(?!\()` [if not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) followed by `(`

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/87aJrQ/4)

The `+` after `*` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) makes it [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) to prevent backtracking at the lookahead.
Instead you could use another word boundary `\b` ([see another demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/87aJrQ/3)).

Comment: Doesn't \d represent [0-9]?

Comment: @ErikE sure, `\d` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *digit* `[0-9]`. If you mean `[^\W\d]` in a negated class with negated word character it's subtracted from `\w` thus leaves `[_a-zA-Z]`. Here to [read more about such constructs](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious) (:

Comment: I get it now, but I think saving 2 characters at the cost of losing clarity is a foolish thing to do.

Comment: @ErikE Yes, absolutely agree with you, but looks funnily doesn't it xD